# Product of 2 graphs

Tags: proof-verification, graph-theory

I have this homework:

We consider the following binary operation on graphs:

if Gi = (Vi, Ei) are two graphs with |Gi| > 2 (i = 1, 2),then G1*G2 is the following graph:

V (G1*G2) = V (G1) × V (G2) and E(G1*G2) = {(u1, u2)(v1, v2) : u1v1 ∈ E(G1),u2v2 ∈ E(G2)}.

The graphs G1 and G2 have at least 2 vertices each.

Prove that G1*G2 is connected if and only if G1 and G2 are connected and one of them contains an odd circuit.

Now we have to prove "=>" and "<="

For "<="

if G1 and G2 are connected and one of them contains an odd circuit then G1*G2 is connected becouse it is complementar of (G1 U G2).

For "=>"

In this case we know that our G1*G2  is connected .Complementar of G1*G2 have 2 connected components.

Do I understand something wrong? Can anyone help me with the demonstration?

I appreciate any indication.

Comment: If $G_1$ has two vertices and one edge, and $G_2$ has two vertices and one edge, then $G_1*G_2$ has four vertices and two edges. $G_1$ and $G_2$ are connected but $G_1*G_2$ is not connected.

Comment: Recall that if $G_1$ and $G_2$ don't have an odd circuit, then they are both bipartite, and we can write $V(G_i) = L(G_i) \cup R(G_i)$ for $i=1,2$.

Then the set $S = (L(G_1)\times L(G_2))\cup (R(G_1)\times R(G_2))$ doesn't have any edges going out to its complement $V \setminus S = (L(G_1)\times R(G_2))\cup (R(G_1)\times L(G_2))$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How demonstre that a graph is connected?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2984207/how-demonstre-that-a-graph-is-connected)